# Can I used rel=author or rel=publisher with Google plus profile for business?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets

As I have seen lots of rich snippets markup in search result which they have done with there individual (person) Google+ profile. And that's great.

So is it legal or not if I used my Google+ business brand profile for the same.

Please have look at the Google+ profile for more information
https://plus.google.com/111362101795597548116

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are talking about the author mark-up that can cause a Google+ provide to be added to a search results.

AFAIK business pages are not currently displayed in rich snippets.

You can define your Google+ business page as the publisher for your website. Maybe in the future this could cause rich snippets.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1708844

Comment: This is right on. They don't currently show in Rich Snippets, but it would be wise to follow the instructions in that link for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's legal. It's just that people are getting used to seeing real faces, and that's what I suspect most people are going to want to see.
You might also want to read the blog post that I've just written, especially if you're using Wordpress: [Author Rel Wordpress](http://milwaukeeseocompany.com/rel-author-wordpress/)